Attempting to JIT compile method EMGUCV in.net maui
I have created .net maui cross platform application and i used .net 8 version.
In mac side ARM64 and release mode when i do any operation related emgu.cv related it's give me exception as below any solutions for this?
Crash :
System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) int Emgu.CV.CvInvoke:CvErrorHandler (int,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,intptr)' while running in aot-only mode. See https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations for more information.

   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at Emgu.CV.MatInvoke..cctor()
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at Emgu.CV.Mat..ctor()
   at AmbirImageEditing.ImageEditingService.CreateMatFromSKBitmap(SKBitmap skBitmap)
   at AmbirImageEditing.ImageEditingService.AllFilterWithSKBitmap(SKBitmap sKBitmap, AdvanceSetting advanceSettingModel)


does emgu use opencv? is opencv "native code"?

Thanks for your feedback, i just fixed this issue, i added lines in csproj file.

-all,Emgu.CV
-all,Emgu.CV.Bitmap

